# How to know if a program was ran using run-as or get the username who is the owner of the current session?

Tags: windows

not using WTS (Terminal Services is not running...)

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/processownersid.aspx). It outlines a .NET solution but as you haven't specified what language/program you are using, if this is not your case, you could see the unmanaged Win32 functions used there.

Comment: Process Owner of a run-as process is the same user that under his token the process is running.